# Dynamic Report page height Odoo 10

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-10

I am using a receipt printer with odoo invoices. I know there is a POS module but I don't want to use that. Sometimes the height of the paper is short and sometimes it's more than it is required. The printer prints extra white paper which is really annoying to put it back inside. so if possible odoo generate reports that fit its content (height) no white spaces at the end. It is a custom report so no header and footer are there.

Comment: Have you looked into the POS report? Please share your report QWeb code, maybe their is something wrong...

Comment: you can manage that from your web browser also in the setting of the print